# How to pass arguments to Module Pattern

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to pass an argument to a module

For example I would like to pass a value for counter when calling the module, smt like

```
testModule.resetCounter(20);
```

(code sample from http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)

```
var testModule = (function () {

  var counter = 0;

  return {

    incrementCounter: function () {
      return counter++;
    },

    resetCounter: function () {
      console.log( "counter value prior to reset: " + counter );
      counter = 0;
    }
  };

})();

// Usage:

// Increment our counter
testModule.incrementCounter();

// Check the counter value and reset
// Outputs: 1
testModule.resetCounter();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a parameter to your `resetCounter` function:

```
resetCounter: function(count) { ... }
```

Comment: just add `if(!count) count=0` because `0+undefined = NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
resetCounter: function (v) {
  console.log( "counter value prior to reset: " + counter );
  counter = (v && (typeof v === "number"))? v: 0;
  console.log( "counter value after reset: " + counter );
}
```

Comment: I would make the parameter optional, defaulting to 0. counter = v || 0;

Comment: @JHurrah good point, edited... Also praying for not passing a "hello" as v